# How to apply subdivision surface to this geometry?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have this simple geometry (I'm using also a mirror modifier) and I want to apply a subdivision modifier. When I add it the geometry gets all messy. I added some loop cuts but the result is not clean. The issue is in the zone where I made a bevel. What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Three points: 1. Subdiv and multires don't go well with ngons, 2. You might want to use "simple" instead of "Catmull Clark" as the algorithm and 3. you actually might have double vertices in your geometry. It's hard to tell without inspecting the file further. You might want to upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , then pasting the link into your question by using the "edit" link below it.

Comment: Also, this seems like a 'hard edge' modeling object, not suited for subdivision. You would probably be better off with a *Bevel* modifier instead, saving a lot of trouble, since it tends to play better with NGons

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Bevel modifier then change ngonal face of your mesh to quads, like in the image below. Then you won't have any troubles with subdivision.[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Thinking about it better, maybe I really don't need a subdivision surface because, yes, it's an hard edge model. I can add only a bevel modifier and it works ok but I need one of the bevels to be bigger (the inside corner). Also, what if I want the part near the mirror to not be bevelled at all? How should I approach that? - I added the blend file to the question.

Comment: I think I'm getting to the solution. I made a bevel in EDIT mode only on the inside edge. Then I selected all the other edges except the one's near the mirror join and added other minor bevels. It seems that the geometry it's ok in this way. If this is the correct way to do it, the only concern I have is that I can't smooth the model after this because on the hard edges I get artifacts.

Comment: Use the edge split modifier then.It will remove artifacts in smooth shading.

Comment: Perfect @Mzidare. That's what was missing!